# Form Handling of vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have two computed to display state data of Vuex:

```
computed:{
    dataTab:function(){
      return this.$store.state.form;
    },
        ...Vuex.mapState({
            mapA: state=>state.form.a
    }),
  },
```

I read some documents about computed. The computed will run Object.defineProperty() to create new property for vue instance. It means dataTab don't have relationtive to this.$store.state.form or mapA don't have relationtive to state.form.a, right? . But when i use v-model to modify dataTab or mapA then state.form.a will change. Why it happened? and why dataTab or mapA don't have setter of computed but it don't show error?

It my code example :https://jsfiddle.net/hoanghung1995/eywraw8t/395022/

Answer (score 1):

So a few misconceptions.

Setting data attributes on a vue instance (Vue.set, data function) will run define property to setup reactive getters and setters.

Computed properties do not use define property.  They use a dependency tracking system when they are calculated so that when something changes that they rely on they can be recalculated.

Your scenario is happening b/c v-model is told to update the a value on an object reference.  If you set the store to strict mode, it will actually warn in the console to let you know that you are mutating the store outside of vuex.

```
var store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
```

One fix, unless you have a great reason to have your form in the store (persisting reloads and you are using vuex for that), i encourage you to look at not putting it there and saving the form data when you initialize the form with some function.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return buildFormData(store)
  },
```

This has a few benefits in my experience

- You aren't using a global state system for keeping track of ephemeral data in a local component
- you can update the data in your form independent of the real data.
- Having reset or undo buttons are relatively easy b/c the data is created with a function, just rerun it
- it is easier to grok for people coming in that are just familiar with vue